# Javascript How to pass specific value from text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

this is my current code from React to get value from cookies:

```
initialTrafficSource: Cookies.get("initialTrafficSource") || null,
```

API Mapping

```
const body = {Source: formValue.initialTrafficSource}
```

Output:
utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set)

what I want is to pass only utmcsr value which is 'direct' even I don't want to include any brackets

let me know if anyone could help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the value you get from cookies. You should create a function so that you can reuse it to get other values as well or you can rewrite the function for better performance just to get the `utmcsr` if you don't care about the other `keys`

```
function getCookieValue(cookieString: string, key: string): string | undefined {
  const cookies = cookieString.split("|").reduce((acc, cookie) => {
    const [key, value] = cookie.split("=");
    acc[key] = value.replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return cookies[key];
}

const body = {Source: getCookieValue(formValue.initialTrafficSource,"utmcsr")}
```